# How to remove notification with a timer but still leave the delete button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is the code I have currently, I am using Javascript, Vue.js.

Messages.length is an array that I have of messages. When you click the x it triggers "clearMessages(item)" which is a function I have in the server side, but I wanted to also create one that calls that if the notification stays there for over 10 seconds.

```
<div v-if="messages.length">
   <div class="notification is-success">
       <p v-for="item in messages">{{ item }}</p>
        <a @click="clearMessage(item)" class="delete"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you notice? Your loop is limited to `p` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` in whatever function adds a message to your array:

```
function addMessage(message) {
  messages.push(message);
  setTimeout(() => clearMessage(message), 10000);
}
```